# Android GridView setOnItemLongClickListener not work after set Visible of child widget of item

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
clientGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            gridClientChooseMode = !gridClientChooseMode;
            clientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    };)
```

and this is the adapter for the gridview:

```
 class ClientListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClientData> {
            public ClientListAdapter(Context context, List<ClientData> list) {
                super(context, R.layout.view_item, list);
            }


            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (gridClientChooseMode) {
                    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
    }
```

checkBox will change its visibility to VISIBLE when gridClientChooseMode=true (when long click on item of the gridview).But after that I cannot turn off the check box because the OnItemLongClickListener didn't work anymore, I mean it works only at first time. Any help is highly appreaciate. Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elltz is right about the CheckBoxes stealing focus. In the layout root view for you grid items, you need the following to prevent the CheckBoxes from getting focus:

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: thanks, you're right. It works now, but i'm wonder that I've only saw a small area of checkbox on the design view, it doesn't take the whole are of view. So why it's take all of the focus? Or because of it's designed like that.

Comment: It's the design. I had a list item with a button that took up a tiny portion of the row but I had the same exact problem. Buttons and CheckBoxes always take the focus off of the grid item or list item and onto themselves.

Answer (score 0):

whiles checkbox is visible it takes away the focus, so either you do put your onlongitemclick listener functions in your checkbox widget onlongclicklistener in your adapter, so it responds to itself and set itself to gone or invisible  or you intercept touch events for the grid or listview, and handle all focus/touch events